# php using two whiles

Tags: php, while-loop

I want to use two whiles at once

```
while( $file = readdir($folder) ) {
```

and

```
while( $file1 = readdir($folder1) ) {
```

I am using the following

```
while( $file = readdir($folder)) && ($file1 = readdir($folder1) ) {
```

but its giving me error:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND

Comment: your code has mis matched parenthesis

Comment: You should read documentation on language syntax more carefully - error is self-explanary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the parenthesis and the fact you are using a single `=` instead of `==`:

```
while( $file == readdir($folder) && $file1 == readdir($folder1) )
```

Comment: The single `=` was probably intentional.

Comment: If you are correct, the right way would be: `while (false !== ($file = readdir($folder)))`